# Does PHP PDO use the same query syntax for the 12 different databases it supports?

Tags: php, pdo

Can I query a all the supported databases via PDO with the same syntax? Or is the syntax database specific? For example can I use the same exact syntax to get all tables from a MySQL database and an Oracle database?

Comment: The syntax is DB specific. Some variations might work on multiple dbs. `Select top ...` wouldn't work on a mysql nor would `select ... from ... limit` work on a mssql.

Comment: You have to keep two things apart: PDO syntax which is invariant and SQL syntax which is (partly) database dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't.

As it said in my [article on PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#why), it's a Database *Access* Abstraction, which means only unified syntax for the database access, but not for SQL.

For the database independent queries you need a special language like [Doctrine's DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)